# Rvar to String when randomizing list comprehension

Tags: string, list, haskell, random

Hey so im trying to pick a random element from this list of list Strings however when i try to add choice to the list comprehension ...

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}
import System.Random(randomRIO)
import Data.Random.Extras(choice)
import Data.Char (digitToInt)
...

getConclusion :: String -> String -> [String]
getConclusion operators atoms =
   choice [[atom1] ++ " " ++ [operator] ++ " " ++ [atom2] | atom1 <- atoms, atom2 <-                     atoms, operator <- operators]
```

... I get this error:

```
/home/joe/Documents/haskell/LAG/main/main.hs: line 56, column 4:
Couldn't match type `Data.RVar.RVarT
                         Data.Functor.Identity.Identity [Char]'
                with `[String]'
  Expected type: [String]
    Actual type: Data.RVar.RVar [Char]
  In the return type of a call of `choice'
  In the expression:
    choice
      [[atom1] ++ " " ++ [operator] ++ " " ++ [atom2] |
         atom1 <- atoms, atom2 <- atoms, operator <- operators]
  In an equation for `getConclusion':
      getConclusion operators atoms
        = choice
            [[atom1] ++ " " ++ [operator] ++ " " ++ [atom2] |
               atom1 <- atoms, atom2 <- atoms, operator <- operators]
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the type of `choice :: [a] -> RVar a`. Your function should have the type `String -> String -> RVar String`. The `RVarT Data.Functor.Identity.Identity [Char]` is just a long synonym for `RVar String`.